# Shopify access token redirects me instead of giving me a token

Tags: oauth, shopify, access-token, shopify-app, shopify-api

When I try to obtain an access token for my app in shopify, instead of returning a

```
{ "access_token": "{{token}}", "scope": "{{scopes}}" },
```

I get a redirect:

(response code: 303)

```
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://{{shop}}.myshopify.com/admin/auth/login">redirected</a>.</body></html>.
```

My request is:

POST

```
https://{{shop}}.myshopify.com/admin/oath/access_token
```

Body:

```
{
"client_id": "{{app_key}}",
"client_secret": "{{app_secret}}",
"code": "{{authorization_code}}"
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you have done the authorization before you reached this step.

I.e `https://{shop}.myshopify.com/admin/oauth/authorize?client_id={api_key}&scope={scopes}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&state={nonce}&grant_options[]={access_mode}`

Also, IIM guessing the values in the curly braces have been replaced with the correct variables :)

Comment: Yes, both are ok. The authorization flow works exactly as described in the shopify docs, except for the access_token return, which puzzles me.